# How to handle transient error during page reload in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reload

When you kick off a `window.location.reload()`, what can you do about the risk of a transient network error interrupting the page load?  Is there some way that the script can persist and monitor the result of the reload to confirm that it succeeded, and if not then wait 30 seconds and try again?

Answer (score 1):

While you can't take control of the browser while it's changing pages, you can check if [`navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine) is true, then reload or wait depending on it.

```js
async function attemptReload() {
  console.log('trying to reload')
  if (!navigator.onLine) {
    console.log('nope')
    setTimeout(attemptReload, 30 * 1000);
    return;
  }
  console.log('yep')
  location.reload();
}

document.querySelector('#reload').addEventListener('click', attemptReload);
```

```html
<button id='reload'>reload</button>
```

Another, perhaps more robust approach, would be to send a `fetch()` to the server. If the requests goes through, then you're OK. If not, then wait just like above.

Comment: Sitting here mulling it over, could I perhaps fetch the whole page into a variable, and then replace the document with my variable if successful?

Comment: @sh1 That would certainly be possible, and would even save you an extra request to the server. My only concern would be that it could mess with the browser, and it wouldn't do some of the normal browser-reloading stuff. If it ends up working for you though, then I don't see any reason to not use it.

Comment: For example, all JavaScript variables would stay the same (unless you reset them) and you wouldn't be able to reinitialize any `const` variables.

Comment: It looks like the reality of my own situation is that by learning a bit more javascript I can simply reload a fragment of the page.  I guess this is why most people do exactly that, and the answer to my original question is "don't do that".